# SVG Line Animation - Squishy Effect

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

### ***Update - solution listed below

I’ve got an svg animation bug I could use some expert help on.

I’m trying to create a similar animation that you can see here (http://springsummer.dk/) when you hover over some of their work (maybe half way down the page) — a line comes in and up and then kind of squishes to the right height.

I recreated this effect in a simple code pen that can be seen here: https://codepen.io/callmegoon/pen/EQRMjG (see code below).

However, in my testing, I came to learn that Safari does not support the negative stroke-dashoffset that I’m using in the animation.

Soooo, I’m trying to figure out a new solution - any ideas?  Totally open to a completely different way to accomplish this (maybe a js solution?), but everything I’m doing hasn’t been working.  My biggest issue has been the squish part at the end where the back/bottom of the line comes up - I haven’t figured out another way to accomplish that without the negative stroke-dashoffset.

Thanks!

```css
/* Draw Line Animations */
  @keyframes drawLine {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 170;
      stroke-dashoffset: 170;
    }
    
    100% {
      stroke-dasharray: 170;
      stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }
  }

  @keyframes unDrawLine {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 170;
      stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }
    
    100% {
      stroke-dasharray: 170;
      stroke-dashoffset: 170;
    }
  }

.box {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.box:hover .line {
  animation: drawLine .6s cubic-bezier(.67,.02,.27,.95) forwards;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  height: 170px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transform: rotate(195deg);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  stroke-dasharray: 170;
  stroke-dashoffset: 170;
  animation: unDrawLine .6s cubic-bezier(.67,.02,.27,.95) forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg class="line" viewBox="0 0 4 170" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="170" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

### Solution (uses GreenSock)

I was able to find a solution that perfectly matched the effect I was going for while also working in Safari - it just required GSAP and the draw plugin.

Solution demo here...
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQqwdo

Solution explanation...
The hack/fix/trick is just slightly animating one of the coordinates of the points in the line - not noticeable to users.